# How can I identify and handle control characters and arrow keys in Perl?

Tags: perl, terminal, arrow-keys

I want to implement the command line features like in a linux terminal. I saw this in ftp command also.

- If I press tab I need to list the commands.
- If I press control characters I need to get that characters based on that I will do some action.
- And if I give any commands it should execute.

For this I tried with [Term::ReadKey](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Term-ReadKey) that is in non-canonical mode. But here I am facing more problems like if I press any control character or arrow I got three characters. For the up arrow I got ASCII 27 91 65.

Can anyone help me out of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got one Perl module to solve my requirement fully.
that is [Term::ShellUI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term::ShellUI).

Thanks for all your inputs.

And If you have any other solution is always welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd be best served by [Term::Readline](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term::ReadLine).

Comment: Nice. But If I press tab I want to list my own commands not files or shell commands.

Comment: For that you may have to drag out your compiler. There is a very well documented example at http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC48

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the generic [Term::ReadLine](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term::ReadLine) interface doesn't include customizable completion features.  You have to pick a particular readline implementation for that.

[Term::ReadLine::Gnu](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term::ReadLine::Gnu), [Term::ReadLine::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Term-ReadLine-Perl/), and [Term::ReadLine::Zoid](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term::ReadLine::Zoid) are all capable of performing custom completion.  Term::ReadLine::Gnu is probably the [best documented](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term::ReadLine::Gnu#Custom_Completion).  Term::ReadLine::Perl is virtually undocumented, and I have no experience with Term::ReadLine::Zoid.